# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).bxSlider is not a function.. in laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel-5.1

it is the first time I use this "bxslider"..i used to get information everywhere but still.. i can't find the exact information i want..

this is the code..which is very short..the problem is.. laravel says bxslider its not a function..

those script above the bxslider with src.. also have an error.. which is "failed to load the resource"..i checked my path and its correct..but still getting the same error..i don't know why.. please help me guys..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('assets/js/jquery.fullPage.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('assets/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js')}}"></script>

<script>
    $(function($){
      $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Is `asset('assets(` valid syntax ? How about `{!!Html::style('css/style.css')!!}
{!!Html::script('js/script.js')!!}` ?

Comment: ..tnx sir.. i change it.. just a typographical error.. but still its isn't working...

Answer (score 1):

To include internal javascript files, you should write like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/jquery.fullPage.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/jquery.bxslider.min.js') }}"></script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ HTML::script('js/jquery.fullPage.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ HTML::script('js/jquery.bxslider.min.js') }}"></script>
```

**Note:** Default path will be your application root. Therefore, your js directory would be located on your application root.